# Comparative construction with two adjectives

Tags: comparative-constructions

I need a little piece of advise.

I am not sure about the right grammatical structure in a comparative sentence with two adjectives, the former with three or more syllables and the latter with only two ones.

Please, look at the two sentences below and compare smart-smarter.

> I think you are **more intelligent and smart** than what it seems.

vs

> I think you are **more intelligent and smarter** than what it seems.

I do personally think that the second question is better than the first one, but I'm not sure though. What's your take on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a native American speaker.

I would swap the order of the adjectives so that you get:

> I think you are smarter and more intelligent than what it seems.

The end of the sentence doesn't sound quite right. An alternative could be:

> I think you are smarter and more intelligent than you seem.

or

> I think you are smarter and more intelligent than you appear.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that "more intelligent and smarter" sounds much more idiomatic. I hesitate to say that "more intelligent and smart" is definitively ungrammatical. "More smart" would be understood (but perhaps be considered infantile). Separating "more" and "smart" by two words may lead to temporary bewilderment.